# How to use variable in send command of Paramiko modules

Tags: python, variables, paramiko

I want to use variable in the command send to the shell

Here is the snippet of code

```
vlans= ["2150"]
def fn():
    client1=paramiko.SSHClient()
    #add missing client key
    client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    #connect to switch
    client1.connect(HOST,username=USER,password=PASS,port=PORT)
    print "SSH connection to %s established" %HOST

    remote_conn = client1.invoke_shell()
    for i in vlans:
      remote_conn.send("\n")
      remote_conn.send("configure \n")
      remote_conn.send("no ManagedElement=1,Transport=1,Bridge=0-26,Vlan=$vlans\n")
      time.sleep(1)
      output = remote_conn.recv(10000)
      print output
    client1.close()

fn()
```

How can I use the variable **vlans** in below line:

remote_conn.send("no ManagedElement=1,Transport=1,Bridge=0-26,Vlan=$vlans\n")

Comment: Do you want `Vlan=i` or `Vlan=vlans`?

Comment: it will be list of vlans like   vlans= ["2150", "2151", "2152",... ]  , so Vlan=i

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.format()`

```
remote_conn.send("no ManagedElement=1,
            Transport=1,Bridge=0-26,Vlan={}\n").format(i)
```

Comment: but what if the this vlans is in the middile or begining of the command ?

Comment: what if I have two variable ?

Comment: File "test-con2.py", line 23, in fn
    remote_conn.send("no ManagedElement=1,Transport=1,Bridge=0-26,Vlan={} \n").format(i)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'format'

Answer (score 0):

the right format should be as below:

```
remote_conn.send("no ManagedElement=1,Transport=1,Bridge=0-26,Vlan={}\n ".format(i))
```

Now it works fine.

Thanks @Ahsanul Haque for hint :)